# Refactoring code using SOLID principles and Design Patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, solid-principles

I am starting to learn C# design SOLID principles and design patterns. I just want to ask what could be the best design pattern to be used to refactor this particular code.

```
using InvoiceApp.Invoices;

namespace InvoiceApp
{
    internal class InvoiceProcessor
    {
        internal void Process(int client)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Processing invoice...");
            Invoice invoice;
            switch (client)
            {
                case 0:
                    invoice = new SimpleInvoice();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    invoice = new InvoiceWithHeader();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    invoice = new InvoiceWithFooter();
                    break;
                case 3:
                case 4:
                    invoice = new InvoiceWithHeaderFooter();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid client");
            }

            invoice.CreateInvoice();

            DisplayInvoice(client, invoice);
            SaveInvoice(client, invoice);
        }


        private void DisplayInvoice(int client, Invoice invoice)
        {
            if (client == 4)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine(invoice.Data);
            } else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(invoice.Data);
            }
        }
        private void SaveInvoice(int client, Invoice invoice)
        {
            string data = invoice.Data;

            //cipher first
            switch (client)
            {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                    data = CaesarCipher(data);
                    break;
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    data = WeirdCipher(data);
                    break;
            }

            File.WriteAllText("Invoice.txt", data);

            Console.WriteLine("Invoice data saved!");
        }

        private string CaesarCipher(string input)
        {
            const int key = 4;
            string output = string.Empty;

            foreach (char ch in input)
            {
                if (!char.IsLetter(ch))
                {

                    output += ch;
                }

                char d = char.IsUpper(ch) ? 'A' : 'a';
                output += (char)((((ch + key) - d) % 26) + d);
            }

            return output;
        }

        private string WeirdCipher(string input)
        {
            return input.Replace('A', '$').Replace('H', '#');
        }
    }
}
```

I know this class violates SRP and maybe Dependency Injection(not sure), but I am having a hard time what could be the best design pattern to use to make the the implementation dynamic and maintainable.

Comment: one quick suggestion, use StringBuilder in place of string in the method `CaesarCipher` if the input string is big

Answer (score 1):

From posted code some thoughts can be considered:

- `switch` statement is often a good candidate to be replaced by `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.
- plentiful using of operator `new` can be encapsulated in some simple factory. This factory will contain various invoices. It looks like each invoice has own algorithm, however these algorithms have the same methods with the same signatures and, I believe, the same behaviour. If it is true then it is a place where [Strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) can be applied:

> Strategy pattern is a behavioral software design pattern that enables selecting an algorithm at runtime. Instead of implementing a single algorithm directly, code receives run-time instructions as to **which in a family of algorithms to use**.

So let me show an example. Let's create our enums for invoices:

```
public enum InvoiceType
{
    SimpleInvoice, InvoiceWithHeader, InvoiceWithFooter, InvoiceWithHeaderFooter
}
```

And using the above enums it would be perfect case to create a simple factory. Simple factory is not [Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) and not [Abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern). To be honest, there is no pattern like *simple factory*. At least, canonical book by GoF does not describe a such pattern.

```
public class InvoiceFactory
{
    private Dictionary<InvoiceType, Invoice> _invoiceByType = new()
    {
        { InvoiceType.SimpleInvoice, new SimpleInvoice() },
        { InvoiceType.InvoiceWithHeader, new InvoiceWithHeader() },
        { InvoiceType.InvoiceWithFooter, new InvoiceWithFooter() },
        { InvoiceType.InvoiceWithHeaderFooter, new InvoiceWithHeaderFooter() },
    };

    public Invoice GetInstanceByType(InvoiceType invoiceType) => 
        _invoiceByType[invoiceType];
}
```

And then our abstraction of invoice class looks like this:

```
public abstract class Invoice
{
    public void Create() { }
}
```

Pay attention to name of method. We are at `Invoice` class and this class according to [Single Responsibility Principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17100/clarify-the-single-responsibility-principle) should be responsible just for `Invoice`. So it can be concluded that `Create()` method should create just `Invoice`. In addition it removes duplication when you use this method. E.g.:

```
invoice.CreateInvoice(); // can be improved to -> please, see the next row
invoice.Create(); // imho, it is nice
```

Then out concrete implentations of `Invoice`:

```
public class SimpleInvoice : Invoice
{
}

public class InvoiceWithHeader : Invoice
{
}

public class InvoiceWithFooter : Invoice
{
}

public class InvoiceWithHeaderFooter : Invoice
{
}
```

And then your class `InvoiceProcessor` would look like this:

```
public class InvoiceProcessor
{
    internal void Process(InvoiceType invoiceType)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Processing invoice...");
        InvoiceFactory factory = new InvoiceFactory();
        Invoice invoice = factory.GetInstanceByType(invoiceType);

        invoice.Create();

        // other code is omitted for the brevity
    }
}
```

Moreover, this design is compliant with the [open/closed principle](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/19627/clarify-the-open-closed-principle).

Answer (score 0):

I think one good option is the Strategy pattern. Please take a look on that.

Answer (score 0):

This class is not doing a lot in the first place. Sure, you can move you initialization to a factory making it more clean, but other than that, the class is processing invoices.